# mysql query ask 2nd table only if !=""

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table customers:

```
id, firstname, lastname, companyname,title_id,salutation_id
1,Peter,Pan,1,1
2,Cindy,Crawfort,Tinysoft,0,1
3,,,Amaton,,,
..
```

and a table title

```
id, name
1. Dr.
2. Dr. Prof.
...
```

and a table salutation

```
id name
1, Mrs.
2,Mr.
3,none
```

What I'd like to do is, to make a query that gives me the correct salutation if it is not empty. 
I tried:

```
select *
from customers
 where if(customer.name!="",customer.title_id=titles.id) and   
       if(customer.name!="",customer.salutation_id=salutations.id) ;
```

That means in a header should be the correct Name if exists. But sometimes, like Amazon you don't have a name, just the companys name to adress. In this case the companys name should only be put out.

An output should look like this:
Mr. Peter Pan
Dear Dr. Peter Pan or

Mrs. Crawfort
Dear Mrs Crawfort

or
Amazon
Dear sirs or madams,

The mentioned query is empty. Any idea? Thank you!
tsunami

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `left join` and some logic in the `select` clause:

```
select c.*,
       (case when s.id is not null and s.id <> '' then s.name
             else t.name
        end) as CorrectSalutation
from customers c left join
     title t
     on c.title_id = t.id left join
     salutation s
     on c.salutation_id = s.id;
```